# Populate and sort issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a small issue with a Mongoose query. I'm trying to populate a collection of shifts with other two referenced collections (employees and shift types).

Everything is okay, the issue is when I try to sort by `"employee.lastName"` key.

This is my code:

```
Shift
  .find()
  .populate("employee", "-_id lastName firstName userID")
  .populate("shift", "-_id shiftID")
  .select("employee date shift")
  .sort({ "employee.lastName": 1, "date": 1 })
  .exec(function(err, shifts) {
    res.status(200).json(shifts);
  });
```

This is a single result:

```
{
  "_id": "5811b23d7b32ae2b59ce5890",
  "shift": {
    "shiftID": "MO123"
  },
  "date": "2016-10-10T00:00:00.000Z",
  "employee": {
    "firstName": "JOE",
    "lastName": "AVERAGE",
    "userID": "AJ456"
  }
},
```

I can't sort my results by `"employee.lastName"` key, simply it doesn't work as expected.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: can you be more precise about the result please? and try also to flatten the json put firstname lastname and userid outside the employee field and see if it works

Comment: i can't put firstName and lastName outside of employee, because they are fields from another collection, attached to result thanks to employee, that is the employee object id-

Answer (score -1):

You can not sort on populate field object. Please sort it on populate

```
Shift
  .find()
  .populate("employee", "-_id lastName firstName userID", null, { sort: { 'lastName': 1 } })
  .populate("shift", "-_id shiftID")
  .select("employee date shift")
  .sort({"date": 1 })
  .exec(function(err, shifts) {
    res.status(200).json(shifts);
  });
```

Comment: thanks but this won't work. this will try to sort by lastName every employee in a single shift, if there would be multiple employees for every shift, but this is not the case. I have one employee for one shift, so I need to sort by lastName not in the employee object but outside it

Comment: var ParticipantSchema = new Schema ({

Comment: II think you should define Shift Schema with employee data is bellow for sort:
var ShiftSchema = new Schema ({
    ......
    employee: {
        _id           : false,
  firstName     : { type: String, trim: true },
        lastName      : { type: String, trim: true },
    },
    ......
})